# Linux shell script, differences between two directories

Tags: linux, bash

I made this code

```
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
echo "use $0 dir1 dir2"
exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d $1 ]; then
echo "$1 nu este un director"
exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d $2 ]; then
echo "$2 nu este un director "
exit 1
fi

a=0
k=1
for $1 in `ls`
do
if [ -f $1 ];  then
a=`exp $a + 1`
fi
done
echo "Ther are $a file "
```

I want to compare two folders and the folder are arguments to the command line.. it should be something like this :  ./script.sh dir1 dir2

But i have this eror :

**./director.sh: line 29: `$1': not a valid identifier
**

I want to count the file from dir1 who is argument to the command line.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Use `for name in *` (avoiding `$1` as it won't do what you expect, and avoiding parsing the output of `ls` as it leads to problems if the file names are not all in the portable file name character set).  Note that `expr` is the 'standard' command for doing addition (not `exp`), but Bash (and POSIX shells) provide alternatives such as `((a++))` or `(($a += 1))` or variations galore on that theme.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is right about your bash script but you might want to simply look at `diff` which does the work nicely: `diff -q dir1 dir2 | sort`

Comment: I know about diff but i need to make this script work.

Comment: I have modify the code and the error doesn't show but i still receive 0 file, and in my folder are 4 file.
a=0
while [ -f $1 ]
do
(($a += 1))
done
echo "Ther are $a files "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the main error:

```
for $1 in `ls`
```

1. `$1` is not a valid variable name
2. [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Do this instead

```
for file in *
```

Also, quote your variables: you want to protect your script from any filenames containing whitespace.

```
if [ ! -d "$1" ]
if [ -f "$file" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this part:

```
a=0
k=1
for $1 in `ls`
do
if [ -f $1 ];  then
a=`exp $a + 1`
fi
done
```

do this:

```
a=$(ls "$1" | wc -l)
```

If you absolutely have to use your looping, change it like this:

```
a=0
for i in ${1}/*
do
    if [ -f "$i" ];  then
        let a=a+1
    fi
done
echo "There are $a files"
```